# Select to create multi-field row showing items missing from list

Tags: sql, oracle

This sounds similar to other questions asked, but I have tried (unsuccessfully) to adapt them... Oracle database, if that matters.
We have sales folks who are assigned any combination of `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH` or `WEST` regions (1, 2, 3 or all 4). I would like to create a table that shows what's missing. So, table `sales_regions` holds:

```
SELECT user, region, current    
FROM sales_regions    
WHERE region IN ('NORTH','EAST','SOUTH','WEST');


USER      REGION   CURRENT
---- -
U1        EAST     Y    
U1        SOUTH    Y    
U2        NORTH    Y    
U3        NORTH    Y    
U3        EAST     Y    
U3        SOUTH    Y    
U3        WEST     Y
```

I am trying to come up with a query that would produce a list that, when combined with the existing one, would give every salesperson every region:

```
USER      REGION   CURRENT    
U1        WEST     N    
U1        NORTH    N    
U2        EAST     N    
U2        SOUTH    N    
U2        WEST     N
```

An old post, containing only 1 field, had the solution:

```
SELECT v.fruit FROM (    
    SELECT 'apple' AS fruit    
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'banana'    
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'carrot') v    
LEFT JOIN friuttable ft ON ft.fruit = v.fruit    
    WHERE ft.fruit IS NULL
```

This seems so close - but I can't get the multi-field query to work...

Comment: Do you have users table? or you will find the missing sales person based on sales_regions table?

Comment: Hi Prakaash - the second option - I'm only worried about those users in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a result set that holds every combination of distinct sales person and region:

```
SELECT t1.user, t2.region
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM sales_region) t1
    ,(SELECT DISTINCT region FROM sales_region) t2;
```

You can then use set operator [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) to get the difference between this table and your table:

```
SELECT t1.user, t2.region
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM sales_region) t1
    ,(SELECT DISTINCT region FROM sales_region) t2
MINUS
SELECT user, region 
FROM sales_region;
```

That should spit out a table that has only the `user`/`region` combinations that aren't already present in your `sales_region` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    WITH sales_regions AS (
  SELECT 'U1' AS username, 'EAST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U1' AS username, 'SOUTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U2' AS username, 'NORTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'EAST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'SOUTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'NORTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'WEST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual ),
  users AS (
    SELECT 'U1' AS username FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'U2' AS username FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'U3' AS username FROM dual),
  regions AS (
    SELECT 'EAST' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SOUTH' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NORTH' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'WEST' AS region FROM dual
  )
  SELECT u.username, r.region, 'N' AS current_
  FROM users u JOIN regions r ON 1=1
  LEFT JOIN sales_regions sr ON u.username = sr.username AND r.region = sr.region
  WHERE sr.username IS NULL
```

Or the MINUS operator if the records are unique or they are not, but you want them to be:

```
    WITH sales_regions AS (
  SELECT 'U1' AS username, 'EAST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U1' AS username, 'SOUTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U2' AS username, 'NORTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'EAST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'SOUTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'NORTH' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U3' AS username, 'WEST' AS region, 'Y' AS CURRENT_ from dual ),
  users AS (
    SELECT 'U1' AS username FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'U2' AS username FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'U3' AS username FROM dual),
  regions AS (
    SELECT 'EAST' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SOUTH' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NORTH' AS region FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'WEST' AS region FROM dual
  )
  SELECT username, region, 'N' AS current_
  FROM (
    SELECT u.username, r.region
    FROM users u JOIN regions r ON 1=1
    MINUS
    SELECT sr.username, sr.region
    FROM sales_regions sr ) t
```

Hope this helps!

PS: Please avoid using keywords as object or column names!

Comment: Thanks, LKomlosi - I am choosing Jnevill's answer for its simplicity/elegance. With minor adjustments, it'll work across my 4-5 sets of data, whereas yours would require a lot of typing... Thanks for your time, though!!